# WPF DragEnter between two Canvas not firing

Tags: wpf, canvas, drag-and-drop, dragenter

I am trying to drag an item from one Canvas to another. I want an event to fire when the object enters the other Canvas. None of the Drag events seem to fire.
I have tried following the solution for this question, but it does not work for me:
[Drag and Drop not responding as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641645/drag-and-drop-not-responding-as-expected)

My canvas is this:

```
<Window x:Class="DragEnterTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="DragEnterMainWindow" Height="460" Width="1000">
<Grid>
    <Canvas Name="Toolbox" Background="Beige" Height="400" Width="200" Margin="12,12,800,35">
        <Rectangle Name="dragRectangle" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Right="0" Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Red"
                   MouseLeftButtonDown="dragRectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown"
                   MouseLeftButtonUp="dragRectangle_MouseLeftButtonUp"
                   MouseMove="dragRectangle_MouseMove"
                   />
    </Canvas>
    <Canvas Background="Azure" Height="400" Margin="218,12,0,35" Name="mainCanvas" Panel.ZIndex="-1"
            DragEnter="mainCanvas_DragEnter"
            DragLeave="mainCanvas_DragLeave"
            PreviewDragEnter="mainCanvas_PreviewDragEnter"
            PreviewDragLeave="mainCanvas_PreviewDragLeave"
            AllowDrop="True"
            DragDrop.Drop="mainCanvas_Drop"
            />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

If I do not have the Panel.ZIndex="-1" then the rectangle is dragged underneath the mainCanvas. This is true even if I set the ZIndex for the rectangle to some positive value.

My code is the following, modified by examples I have found:

```
namespace DragEnterTest
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private bool _isRectDragInProg;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void dragRectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        _isRectDragInProg = true;
        dragRectangle.CaptureMouse();
    }

    private void dragRectangle_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        _isRectDragInProg = false;
        dragRectangle.ReleaseMouseCapture();
    }

    private void dragRectangle_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_isRectDragInProg) return;
        // get the position of the mouse relative to the Canvas
        var mousePos = e.GetPosition(Toolbox);

        // center the rect on the mouse
        double left = mousePos.X - (dragRectangle.ActualWidth / 2);
        double top = mousePos.Y - (dragRectangle.ActualHeight / 2);
        Canvas.SetLeft(dragRectangle, left);
        Canvas.SetTop(dragRectangle, top);
    }

    private void mainCanvas_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string t = "Test";  // Never enters this event
    }

    private void mainCanvas_DragLeave(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string t = "Test";  // Never enters this event
    }

    private void mainCanvas_PreviewDragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string t = "Test";  // Never enters this event
    }

    private void mainCanvas_PreviewDragLeave(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string t = "Test";  // Never enters this event
    }

    private void mainCanvas_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string t = "Test";  // Never enters this event
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not dragging anything actually, just moving rectangle here and there in canvas.

You'll need to call `DragDrop.DoDragDrop` function when your rectangle leave the source, also detach it from source so that you can add it to target later.

```
    // Drag - In mousemove event when mouse has gone out of toolbox
    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(
        Toolbox, 
        new DataObject("MyWPFObject", rectangle),
        DragDropEffects.Move
    );

    // Drop - In Drop event of target
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("MyWPFObject"))
    { 
       var rectangle = e.Data.GetData("MyWPFObject") as Rectangle
    ....
```

[Tutorial ...](http://wpftutorial.net/DragAndDrop.html)

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer.
I have not gotten it to work with what I really want (my example is very simple). It seems that I must make a lot of code myself. But your easy explanation was very good in making me understand a lot more about what constitutes a drag and drop (in WPF). For this, I thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because you're capturing the mouse, so all mouse events are being handled by your dragged `Rectangle`, and they don't get passed on to your `Canvas`

I personally had all kinds of problems with using WPF's built-in drag/drop functionality, so I ended up using `MouseEvents` instead.

The solution I used was from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2639399/302677), and went like this:

1. On `MouseDown` with left button down, record the position (on `MouseLeave` erase the position)
2. On `MouseMove`, if left button down, position is recorded, and current mouse position differs by more than delta, set a flag saying drag operation is in progress & have your application (not the dragged object) capture the mouse
3. On `MouseMove` with drag operation in progress, use hit testing to determine where your rectangle should be (ignoring the rectangle itself) and adjust its parenting and position accordingly.
4. On `MouseUp` with drag operation in progress, release the mouse capture and clear the "drag operation is in progress" flag

Comment: Hi Rachel, Thank you for your answer.
I do not understand the panel mentionend in your 3rd point. Do you mean rectangle, or is there some panel required that I do not know about?
Also your 2nd point: Have your application capture the mouse: Do you have some example? I do not knwo what you mean here.

In the real programme, I am creating an object which looks the same, but has its own events, and it is this object that I am dragging and dropping (but only if it lands on the right canvas, otherwise it should dissapear).

Comment: @user1497953 Sorry, that should be `Rectangle` not `Panel`. I'll update it. Also your current code has the dragged `Rectangle` capturing the mouse so any mouse events get handled by the `Rectangle` object only. I was looking through some of my old code, and I have one with all the mouse capture statements commented out, and another one using `e.MouseDevice.Capture(this as IInputElement);` where `e` is `MouseEventArgs` from a `MouseMove` event, and `this` being `Application.Current.MainWindow`

Comment: Hi again,
I have only been using the events in their default way - therefore I am not able to glean the right structure from what you have written. Do you (or any) know of some references on how to capture events in another context? (Escalating events?) I would still want to be able to get the single moved element amongst numerous elements that might be identical (and overlapping the dragged element). Thank you again.

Comment: @user1497953 I started with [Bea Stollnitz's article on dragging/dropping databound items](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=53). I'd highly recommend you check it out - perhaps it can point you to your solution.